# why some project use fetch_assoc instead of fetch_all in mysqli

Tags: php, string, variables

why some project use fetch_assoc in a while loop instead of fetch_all in php:mysqli?

Comment: What about the others fetch_​all,
fetch_​array,
fetch_​assoc,
fetch_​field_​direct,
fetch_​field,
fetch_​fields,
fetch_​object,
fetch_​row ?  Perhaps RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're identical when used like in your example, but `fetch_all` wasn't available until PHP5.3. So for older code, using `fetch_assoc` was the only option.

There is probably also a bit of tradition here, since `fetch_assoc` mirrors how you'd write the code using the old `mysql_` extension.

Remember that you'll have to give `fetch_all` `MYSQLI_ASSOC` if you want it to behave like `fetch_assoc`.